# JavaScript basic array and function problems

Tags: javascript

```
var a=[1,2,3];
var b = a;
a[1]=4;
alert(a);
alert(b);
```

I cannot figure out why is the array B is [1,4,3] as well.

My second question is: how can I complete the function sum(a)(b), so it will return the value of a+b. For example if call sum(2)(4) it will return 6?

Answer (score 6):

The reason why B gets mutated as well is that when you assign
`var b = a`, you are not copying the array.  In javascript, arrays are objects and variables that hold object data are merely references to the object.  The line `a[1] = 4` changes the object both `a` and `b` are referencing.

For the second question, you want a curried version of `sum`.  You can implement it simply as
`const sum = a => (b => a + b);`
Then `sum(a)` is the function `b => a + b`.

Answer (score 0):

In JS `var Arr1 = Arr1` does not copy it, it simply puts the reference to the array into another variable. (see [@Adam Jaffe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46897649/2119863)'s answer)

If you are attempting to have 2 different arrays, *clone* the first one by slicing it at starting position.

```js
var a=[1,2,3];
var b = a.slice(0);
a[1]=4;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a =[1,2,3];
var b = [];
b = a.concat(b);
a[1]=4;
alert(a);
alert(b); 

function sum(a, b){
 return a + b;
}

var r = sum(2, 4);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function sum(a,b)
{
  return a+b;
}

var a=[1,2,3];
var b = a.slice(0);
a[1]=4;
alert(a);
alert(b);

var c=sum(2,4);

alert("c=" + c);
```

Comment: Author asked for a function that he can invoke this way: `sum(a)(b)` and not `sum(a,b)`.